# Were there changes to AppStore 'password caching' in iOS 7?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, password

Ever since I updated my iPad mini to iOS 7, my son (4 y.o.) has been making sneaky in-app purchases. What's worse is he *knows* how he's doing it, but won't spill the beans when I ask him how. Whatever his 'trick' is, it doesn't *seem* to work on our other iPad, which has not been updated to iOS 7.

I think I figured it out last night. After I input my password to install a (free) application, it seems he can hop in to an app and make a purchase using the 'cached' password. In the past I thought the password would be requested again for in-app purchases.

Have there been any changes to AppStore passwords in iOS 7, specifically the length of time before the password will be asked for again, or a change that allows in-app purchases during the 'caching' period? Or is this simply a change in his behavior?

<sub>I've disabled in-app purchases now. Slightly annoying but it does solve the problem.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave in-app purchases on if you wish.

Once you have enabled `Restrictions` then at the bottom of the second section, `Allowed Content` you will see `Require Password` and underneath they even have a little prompt `Require password for purchases`.

Change this from the default of `15 minutes` to `Immediately` and your problem is fixed.